# Changing a IQueryable synchronous method to async

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I want to convert my code to async but i get error converting types,how can i turn this code to async?

```
public IQueryable<MyProject.Models.Campaign> Where(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<MyProject.Models.Campaign, bool>> predicate)
{
    try
    {
        return db.Campaigns.Where(predicate);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't post anything that executes a query. `Where` simply creates a *new* query, it doesn't execute it. `ToListAsync()` or `ToArrayAsync()` ar ethe methods that do execute the query

Comment: Besides, unless `predicate` is null, `Queryable.Where` won't throw which makes this method nothing more than an alias for `Where()` itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your answer,but this is a repository method where i want to call it in my controller.

Comment: that doesn't make it any less problematic, or more usefull. If you can call that method, you can call IQueryable's `Where`. Unless you used the generic repository *anti*pattern to wrap a higher level abstraction like an ORM and LINQ under a *low*-level abstraction like a repository. "Generic" repositories are nothing more than the `DbSet<T>`'s in a context. A *real* repository should abstract complex data access patterns, not simply alias an ORM's implementation. What happens if you move to eg a microORM like Dapper?

Answer (score -3):

i found out how to do that , the problem was i had to change IQueryable to IList.

```
public async Task<IList<MyProject.Models.Campaign>> WhereAsync(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<MyProject.Models.Campaign, bool>> predicate)
{
    try
    {
        return await db.Campaigns.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That means you will query the database. `ToListAsync()` materializes the query.

Comment: Can you give us a code example where will you use this newly created method?

Comment: The `IQueryable.Where` function will not connect with db until you call `ToList` function, there is no sync problem here. If you want it 'async', you should just use `var list = await db.Campaigns.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();` in your main function.

Comment: @shaaraa no, the answer is not correct. The *question* was wrong to begin with as `Where()` doesn't execute anything. What you did in this case though will load *all* results, even if you need just a single property from each record. With the original code you could have added a `Select(campain=>campaign.Name).ToListAsync()` and select only the names. Now, you're loading the entire Campaign object, whether you want it or not

Comment: @shaaraa it's also not safe or secure - any problem will simply get hidden by that `catch` and no-one will know something broke. Returning a `null` can result in NRE exceptions later on